# Do there exist x such that K(xx)<K(x), where K is Kolmogorov complextity.

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Let $K(x)$ denote the Kolmogorov complexity of a string $x$. Do there exist a string such that $K(xx)<K(x)$. (Here $xx$ is the concatenation of $x$ with itself). A similar but different question was asked [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/kolmogorov-complexity-of-d-and-dd), but the counterexample given in the answer to that question doesn't work for this one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am no expert on Kolmogorov complexity, but I think that such *x* can be constructed for every complexity function K as follows.  Since 1, 11, 1111, 11111111, …, 1<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>, … is an encoding of a natural number *n*, K(1<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>) cannot be o(log *n*).  However, when *n*=2<sup>*m*</sup>, obviously K(1<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>)=K(1<sup>2<sup>2<sup>*m*</sup></sup></sup>)=O(log *m*)=O(log log *n*).  Therefore the sequence K(1), K(11), K(1111), K(11111111), …, K(1<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup>), … cannot be weakly monotonically increasing, which means that there exists a string *x* in the form 1<sup>2<sup>*n*</sup></sup> such that K(*xx*) < K(*x*).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, Is there an incompressible string $x$ such that $K(xx)\lt K(x)$?

Comment: I think that $K(1^{2^{2^m}})=O(\log m)$ and K(1^{2^n})=Ω(log n) contradict each other. What he mean is: If $f(n)=o(\log n)$ then $K(1^{2^n})\neq O(f(n))$. Otherwise the proof seems fine.

Comment: This seems to work. Indeed, I think it gives you an infinite sequence of such strings. However, either I am misunderstanding something, or the statement of the chain rule for Kolmogorov Complexity that appears in wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_for_Kolmogorov_complexity) is then wrong. 

Initially I thought that wikipedia's definition might not apply here, as there you have to be able to know where does X end and Y begin, while here this seems not to be required, but when Y = X you can add that to the description in O(1) by saying "split in the middle".

Comment: @Sune: The notation Ω(⋅) has several slightly different definitions.  “K(1^2^n)=Ω(log n)” in my answer means “limsup K(1^2^n)/log n > 0,” and it does not contradict “K(1^2^2^m)=O(log m).”  I edited the answer to clarify this point.  See also [Which definition of asymptotic growth-rate should we teach?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/which-definition-of-asymptotic-growth-rate-should-we-teach)

Comment: @turkistany: I do not know the answer.

Comment: @Abel: I do not know the exact statement of the chain rule for Kolmogorov complexity (in particular, which definition of the O(⋅) notation is used in Wikipedia).

Comment: @turkistany and all: Note that it is always true that K(xx)>K(x)-c for some constant, I thought this should be pointed out. This also means that we need a very precise definition of incompressible if we want to study this question. I would guess the answer is again yes, but I don't have a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Kolomogorov complexity in practice does depend on your model. Turing machine, Java program, C++ program,... if there is an idiosyncrasy in your model that allows for this to happen on a finite set of inputs it is no problem.

The better question is how much of this behavior can you get away with and still have the model be a universal.

Comment: I think a better question is: Does such x exist for all models? I don't know what a "model" is formally, but it seems that Tsuyoshis answer works for all reasonable programming languages.

Comment: You can assign $0$ to $xx$ and something larger for $x$ and still have a universal model.

Answer (score 1):

@Tsuyoshi:

I didn't understand well your proof.

Assume that we pick a standard Turing Machine as "description language" defining $K(s)$ as the number of states of the smallest TM that starts with an empty tape and halts after printing the **string** $s$ on it.

Did you proved that we can build a $TM_{ss}$ that "prints" the string $ss = 1111...1 = 1^{2^{n+1}}$ on the tape and is built with **fewer** states than $TM_{s}$ that "prints" the string $s = 1^{2^n}$ ?

Can your proof be applied to Kolmogorov complexity on TMs ?

**OK! I GOT IT** ... when $n+1 = 2^{m}$ the $TM_{ss}$ can be "powered" with a new "inner loop" (we add some states but we can remove many states that in $TM_{s}$ are needed for "counting" $n$) ... Thanks!

(sorry, but I don't know how to post this as comment)

Comment: To [write a comment](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) on a post made by someone other than you which is not an answer to your question, you need reputation point at least 50.